# Core data not saving duplicate entries

Tags: core-data

I have been searching all over for that but all i can find is the opposite of what i am looking for. If i save twice the value 10 for example, core data only save it once ! i am fetching all of the entries of an attributes array in order to add them but if there is the same number twice in that array its adding it only once ! when the array is suppose to be 10,10,10,5,5,1,1 the total would be 42 but what i get is an array with 10,5,1 for a total of 16. all i keep getting when i search for it is how to make sure to not get duplicate. I would like to show some code but since i have no idea where is that issue happening it would be a lot of code to put in here. if anyone as a clue of what is happening i would appreciate a quick help.

Thank you

Comment: Show your data model, the array property, the code where you add to the array and the code where you test the contents of the array.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered. There is no general situation that would cause this, so without more detail on how your app manages this data, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: SOLUTION : i had my [request setReturnsDistinctResults] set to YES ! has to be set to NO ! thanks anyway ! easy fix are nice once in a while !